# MySQL How to retrieve data from table directly to variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

That's just my php snippet:

```
$cookies=$_COOKIE['rwt'];
$user =mysql_query("SELECT user FROM users WHERE cookies='$cookies'");
```

How can I retrieve data from MySQL table, directly to variable $user?Now I get strange result: Resource id #10

Comment: If this happens to be your actual code, please have a look at [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Gumbo Now I use mysql_real_escape_string and htmlentities(from XSS) to prevent this sort of attacks. Is it enough?

Comment: Only if you use it for *each and every* value. (Note that this can’t be used for anything other than a value, e. g. a SQL keyword, identifier, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch a row from the result handle you get:

```
$user = mysql_query(blah blah blah);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
echo $row['user'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Without fetching an array you can get a single column value with mysql_result();

```
$cookies=mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['rwt']);
$userResource =mysql_query("SELECT user FROM users WHERE cookies='{$cookies}'");
$user=mysql_result($userResource,0,"user");
```

Comment: It returns an error Warning:  mysql_result()Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 10

Comment: There might be something wrong with your query, use mysql_error() to find out